# Updating to AndroidStudio 3.2, when trying to build I get an issue: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using generation folder

Tags: android, annotations, build.gradle, android-manifest, android-annotations

The full problem is:

```
error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation folder [/Users/gopublic/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/131073/REF-RD-VRANDROID/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug])
```

This is how my build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
mavenLocal()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

def AAVersion = '4.4.0'
dependencies {
// AndroidAnnotations
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'

// Support libraries
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'

// Mosby mvp
implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp-lce:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp-nullobject-presenter:3.0.0'

// Gson
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

// EventBus
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

// YoYo
implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.2@aar'

// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

// Android SpinKit
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'

// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

// OkHTTP
testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

// RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'

// Expandable Layout
implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'

// Apache Common Collections
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'

//Google Analytics
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nl.dtt.refcom4all"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.4.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-fexceptions"
        }
    }
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'alias here'
        keyPassword 'password here'
        storeFile file('keystore/release-keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'password here'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "/Users/gopublic/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/131073/REF-RD-VRANDROID/changelog.txt"
    }

    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        ext.enableCrashlytics=true
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "/Users/gopublic/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/131073/REF-RD-VRANDROID/changelog.txt"
    }

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/ts3_sdk_3.0.4/bin/android']
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
}
```

This works perfectly on my machine (running the same, latest version of AS 3.2) but on my build machine, it gets this error. Any ideas what I can do, regarding this?
Is there possible to be a difference in the way AndroidStudio settings are set, that could cause this?

Answer (score 3):

I reverted to using  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'` instead of `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` and that worked